# How to capture data coming from an AJAX enabled web site?

Tags: .net, ajax, web-crawler

Some time ago I created an application to dynamically capture data from an asp site navigating it, parsing the html pages I got and storing the selected data into a database.

Now I need to do the same again but this time the web site is developed using AJAX and I don't know how to face the problem. Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest two ways of solving you problem:

1) if you create a crawler for one particular site with tons of data to retrieve, write these requests manually (using WebRequest class, for example)

2) if you need universal solution, try some GUI testing tools (Selenium, Telerik WebAii etc.) to run browser into site, so JS and AJAX will be executed by browser.

Depends on you.

Comment: I will crawl only one site (a stock exchange one) and I will record it's data to a database. The site uses AJAX to refresh the stock information on screen. So do you think that I can use HttpWebRequest class to do the job?

Comment: @SoMoS Sure. I was automating load tests for AJAX-powered sites, and my workflow was like that: use Fiddler to capture AJAX requests, get idea what is going on and then use HttpWebTestRequest to automate it.

Comment: @SoMoS I used Visual Studio Team Suite 2008 for that, but usual HttpWebRequest should give you same abilities except multithreaded testing, which you don't need.

Comment: @SoMoS And, well, this introspection can be _boring_ :)

Comment: +1 'cos you made me laugth :D Ok, I already fiddled the thing and looks quite clear. I also have the javascripts that the site use to do  the requests so I think this shouldn't be hard. The only thing I'm not sure about is if the https connection will make things harder. Thanks for your answers!